# dpkg-reconfigure gives me a message that a package is not installed

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am running 12.04.5 LTS on linux 3.13.0-65-generic kernel

When I run `dpkg-reconfigure -a`, it gives me the following:

```
Package `flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound' is not installed and no info is available.
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound is not installed
```

I purged and reinstalled the package using `apt-get`, and there's no change.

Also, when I run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep "^xserver" | tr '\n' ' ')`, I get:

```
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: xserver-common-lts-trusty is broken or not fully installed
```

When I run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep 'lts-raring' | tr '\n' ' ')` I get:

```
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-raring:i386 is broken or not fully installed
```

How should I fix it?

---

`apt-cache policy flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound` gives:

```
flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound:i386:
  Installed: 0.0.svn2431-3ubuntu1
  Candidate: 0.0.svn2431-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 0.0.svn2431-3ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/multiverse i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`sudo apt-get install -f` gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

`uname -a` gives:

```
Linux liuwx-ThinkPad-T420 3.13.0-65-generic #105~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 22 13:22:42 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've done all the autoclean and autoremove stuff, and they don't give any errors. But it seems I have some serious broken package issues.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound` and the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: The output of `uname -a`

Comment: Are there reasons for the i386 packages?

Comment: I have no idea. I guess when I was installing the drivers I followed some improper instructions for my computer.

Comment: First remove the i386 package via `sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound:i386` and add the output into your question.

Comment: After that install `libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-trusty` via `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-trusty`

Comment: And `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-common-lts-trusty`

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before and generally, I've been told that "this can be safely ignored as there is no up-to-date package that comes with dpkg to install the specific package".

I didn't believe them, though, and neither should you. I dug a bit deeper, used bleachbit (as root) to clear all extra caches, ran apt-get update, and then found the package from it's source repository. Then, I put it in dpkg's folder and it seemed to work (I do not remember if I modified it or not, but you should not need to). Of course, in my situation it involved virtual-box, which isn't the easiest thing to force on ubuntu (it wasn't when I tried), but the results are the same. With very little tweaking, you should be able to get [this package file (source Debian)](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/i386/flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound/download) to work perfectly.

I apologize that I cannot be more helpful, but it was over 6-months ago that I had an issue of this kind.

Comment: It's okay, thanks for your answer. There seems to be some complex dependencies because there were hundreds of broken packages in the log. I removed many of them and the update proceeded, then after the update my computer cannot boot. I guess I'm going to do a fresh install instead lol

Comment: Make sure to backup your home directory! Funny thing, I did that to mine once doing THE SAME THING! Good to know I'm not the only one. Good luck!